# How to get the empty array in Json Auto - SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2019

I have the below query to convert to Json object. If there was no data in the join tables, I need to display empty array []. How can I do it?

Here is my sample query

```
SELECT a.Name,                                    
       a.ID,
       a.TypeID,                                     
       a.Shared,
       a.Description,                               
       a.CreatedBy, 
       a.CreatedByName, 
       a.CreatedDate,
       a.ModifiedBy,
       a.ModifiedByName,
       a.ModifiedDate,
       b.StudentID,
       b.StudentName,
       c.RoomID,
       c.RoomName
    FROM TableA a
      LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.ModelID =  b.ModelID
      LEFT JOIN TableC c ON b.StudentID = c.StudentID                           
        FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('JsonModel'), INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Instead of empty array ([]) I am getting the null values for the join tables. How can I fix the above query to get the empty array if there was no data in Join tables.

Comment: Wouldn't removing `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` give you what you're looking for?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/include-null-values-in-json-include-null-values-option?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I need INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES because if there any null values, I need to show the null field. If I remove INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES missing the null fields in the Json object. How do I handle NULL values and empty objects?

Comment: @Larnu Do you have any idea about this one?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Do you have any idea about this query?